# How can I loop over pair in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, std-pair

I am trying to print the elements in pair, but it's throwing an error: "no matching function call"

 
Code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    pair<int, string> pairVec;
    pairVec = make_pair(1, "One");
    pairVec = make_pair(2, "Two");
    pairVec = make_pair(3, "Three");
    for(auto iter:pairVec)
    {
        std::cout << "First: " << iter.first << ", Second: "
                  << iter.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting `pairVec`. Hint: It is a single pair, not a `vector` of `pair`s.

Comment: How many elements do you expect to see printed?

Comment: What would the type of `iter` be? Try to fill in the type yourself, without writing `auto`.

Comment: **What is the expected behavior of your code?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not making a vector at all. You probably wanted to do this instead:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<pair<int, string>> pairVec;  // create a vector of pairs
    pairVec.emplace_back(1, "One"); // adding pairs to the vector
    pairVec.emplace_back(2, "Two");
    pairVec.emplace_back(3, "Three");
    for (auto iter : pairVec) {
        std::cout << "First: " << iter.first << ", Second: "
        << iter.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!
Did I mention about the vector? I just need to iterate over the pair and print the elements

Comment: @DheerajN *Did I mention about the vector?* Yes you very much did. Why did you `#include <vector>`? Why did you call your variable `pairVec`?

Comment: @Blaze  It is working fine! But when I mention the type of iterator instead of auto: std::vector<pair<int, string>>::const_iterator it, with regular for loop using it.begin....., it is throwing error "has no member named ‘first’"

Comment: @DheerajN that's because the definition in that regular loop is different than what was `auto`-defined with the range based for loop (which is something rather unwieldy, in MSVC at least). But that works if you change ` iter.first` to `iter->first` and likewise for `iter.second`.

Comment: The purpose of the `std::pair` here is to put order into the elements on the right hand side (`std::pair.second`). How would you change order, like swapping elements std::vector<std::pair<3, ...>> with std::vector<std::pair<8, ...>> ? Cheers